# In MVN project, my code looking for property file at user directory instead of target/classes

Tags: java, macos, maven

I have a property file at src/main/resource in my maven project, during runtime i know it looks for resources under target/classes in maven project but in my case its looking at user dir in **MAC** and failed with NULL PTR exception

FYI, I have tried below

1. MVN clean compile test install  etc
2. Another version of eclipse
3. Reinstalled java

But nothing worked

Comment: You must add code where you are accessing the property file.

Comment: The Maven standard dirs for resources are [`src/main/resources` and `src/test/resources`](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html), not `src/resource`.

Comment: Sorry i missed it to add it here.. It's there only src/main/resources

Comment: I don't want to hard code the path src/main/resources, In another machine where its picking property file from target/classes its working but actually file resides at src/main/resource

Comment: @Lokesh You don't have to hardcode that. These paths are for build time only anyway. During build the Maven Resources Plugin copies the files therein to `target/classes` and `target/test-classes`. The Maven JAR|WAR|... Plugin|s place main resources in the artifact's root.

Comment: @GeroldBroser, Thanks for your clarification, but how to keep that main resources in the artifact's root ? [I have seen in build path its set target/classes as output folder as well]

Comment: @Lokesh What does „_how to keep that main resources in the artifact's root_“ mean now? In your Q you wrote „_its looking at user dir [...] with NULL PTR exception_“. These are two opposite endpoints of resource processing: source and sink. How did you find out that Maven is looking for main resources in your user dir? Is there any build log output you can supply? Is there any hard/soft link in your file system? Have you seen [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) already?

Comment: You should use `xyz.getClass().getResourcesAsStream("/xyz.input")` which means it's loaded as a resource. This will work within the resulting jar as well. By using `/` the resource will be searched in the root of resources which is in other words `/target/classes`...Really calling `mvn clean compile test install` ? If so just use `mvn verify` instead....

Comment: @GeroldBroser, while debugging I have seen the base path as user directory based on that I mentioned maven is pointing to that location where as in other machine same base path is pointing to target/classes where it is working for them

Comment: @khmarbaise, let me try that